# ¿Se puede compartir la cuenta de MercadoPago con dos sitios de venta y URLs distintas?

Tags: post, url, mercadopago

La plataforma de ecommerce es multiportal, lo cual nos permite crear mas de un sitio de venta con URLs/MARCAS distintas, lo cual se ajusta a nuestra necesidad de negocio, pero la gestion de cobros nos gustaria mantenerla centralizada, entonces, se puede compartir la cuenta de MP? con respuestas a dos sitios identificados con URL distintas?

Gracias.
Slds.-

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque parece no estar relacionada con la programación o las herramientas de programación. Lee en el Centro de Ayuda: "[¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"

Comment: Eso no sería una pregunta para la empresa MercadoPago? Me imagino que podría involucrar condiciónes de negocio también.

Comment: Disculpen mods, pero la respuesta es técnica y no de negocio.
Mercado Pago permite a través de la opción "Connect" con una única integración poder cobrar en representación de varias cuentas. Más info en: https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/mercadopago-connect/